# The insert APPEARS to work, but doesn’t in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert-into, percona

this is a very strange issue...

```
select count(*) from imprint_users;
count 461

INSERT INTO  coresource.imprint_users (imprint_sid, users_sid) VALUES (2387,165);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

select count(*) from imprint_users;
count 461
```

1) cannot see anything in mysql-error

2) checked the status of the table just in case

```
+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table                    | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| coresource.imprint_users | check | status   | OK       |
+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

3)here is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE "imprint_users" (
"imprint_sid" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
"users_sid" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("imprint_sid","users_sid"),
KEY "FK__IMPRINT_U__IMPRI__47E69B3D" ("imprint_sid"),
KEY "FK__IMPRINT_U__USERS__48DABF76" ("users_sid"),
CONSTRAINT "fk__imprint_u__impri__47e69b3d" FOREIGN KEY ("imprint_sid")    REFERENCES "imprint" ("imprint_sid"),
CONSTRAINT "fk__imprint_u__users__48dabf76" FOREIGN KEY ("users_sid") REFERENCES "users" ("users_sid")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

4) This is in a M-M setup and we are writing to M1
Server version: 5.6.24-72.2-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 72.2,
Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: In your insert, you specify the schema, but you don't specify the schema in your selects. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you have two tables with the same name.

Comment: to confirm what you requested...did all the steps including the schema and still no change

i have crossed checked the list of tables and there is no duplication.

Comment: Do you have auto-commit turned off? I don't know anything about Percona, but try adding a `START TRANSACTION` before the insert statement and `COMMIT` after the insert.

Comment: autocommit=on is already enabled

funny.. when i did start transaction and inserted and checked the  table... it did insert the value


@Travesty3 -- tried other random tables on the same schema w/o being tran and commit and the work. Accept this 1 table that just started happening.

Answer (score 0):

try a test. 
first you flush table & autocommit is set to zero then set it to 1.

```
flush table;
set @autocommit=1;
select count(*) from imprint_users;
INSERT INTO  coresource.imprint_users (imprint_sid, users_sid) VALUES (2387,165);
select count(*) from imprint_users;
```

If still the problem remains then see is there any TRIGGER OR EVENT working in background. So disable all triggers, disable the entire scheduler (all events)-

```
SET @disable_triggers = 1;
SET @event_scheduler = OFF;
```

run the query & test

Comment: show variables --> event_scheduler=OFF
when the above was done it does not insert data into the table.

Comment: there was no change. the app team wanted to bounce the box. once online issue was resolved. 

At this point clueless as to what was wrong with that 1 table.
thanks for the direction.